# Biber silently fails

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a LaTeX project and I am trying to compile it on a macOS Big Sur (MacTeX distro).
I use the following command:

```sh
INTERACTION=errorstopmode
OUTDIR=dist
JOBNAME=report
SYNCTEX=1

latexmk -cd -dvi- -f -pdf -ps- -time \
    -jobname=${JOBNAME} \
    -outdir=${OUTDIR} \
    --synctex=${SYNCTEX} \
    --interaction=${INTERACTION} \
    main
```

I scaled down the project up to MWE, like this (`main.tex`):

```tex
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        style=numeric,
        giveninits=true,
        sorting=nyvt,
        maxbibnames=1000
    ]{biblatex}
    \bibliography{bibfile}

    \begin{document}

        \title{Report title}
        \author{Report Authors}
        \date{}

        \maketitle

        \begin{abstract}
            Abstract goes here.
        \end{abstract}

        \section{Introduction}

            Intro goes here.
            And one reference~\cite{practical-ore}.

        \printbibliography%

    \end{document}
```

and the `bibfile.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{practical-ore,
  author    = {Chenette, Nathan and Lewi, Kevin and Weis, Stephen A. and Wu, David J.},
  title     = {Practical Order-Revealing Encryption with Limited Leakage},
  booktitle = {Fast Software Encryption},
  year      = {2016},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  pages     = {474--493}
}
```

I was able to see this in the logs.
I believe, the execution is not supposed to stop after `Found BibTeX data source`.

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'dist/report.blg'
[94] biber-darwin:322> INFO - === Thu Mar 18, 2021, 22:28:25
[118] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'dist/report.bcf'
[232] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 3 citekeys in bib section 0
[249] Biber.pm:4256> INFO - Processing section 0
[250] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source 'bibfile.bib'
[250] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source 'bibfile.bib' to bibfile.bib
[264] Biber.pm:4455> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibfile.bib' for section 0
[265] bibtex.pm:1653> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[271] bibtex.pm:1471> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibfile.bib'
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: run `biber --cache` , this will report a file, delete it and try again (be then patient as biber will have to recreate the cache).

Comment: Wow, that worked!
Mind posting an answer I will accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the cache of biber gets corrupted and need to be remade.

Run `biber --cache`, this will report a file, delete it and try again (be then patient as recreating the cache needs some time).

Comment: Problem occurred again and this command didn't help. This one did: `rm -rf $(biber --cache)`